# how to list the installed app in device by flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Im get tired to find sutable package for this work ! every packages didnt work or deprecated some body please  suggest me an package thats really work thanks

Comment: Did you try `installed_apps` package (https://pub.dev/packages/installed_apps)?

Comment: yes but it dosnt work ! I do exact same as the code of that give me unimplemented ....

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want? If you just want the list of installed apps on your device then `installed_apps` is working just fine. If you want something else then please clarify. If you just want the list of apps then I can add the code in the answer.

Comment: Software suggestions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use [installed_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/installed_apps) package to get the list of apps installed on your android device. I'm not certain about iOS but I think it won't work for iOS.

For using `installed_apps`:

First add it to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
installed_apps: ^1.3.0
```

Make sure you do the indentation properly as:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  installed_apps: ^1.3.0
  ...
```

Make sure to import the package in the file where you need to use it as such:

```
import 'package:installed_apps/installed_apps.dart';
```

To just print all the app names you can do something like this:

```
Future<void> printAllAppNames() async {
  List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps();

  for (AppInfo a in apps) {
    print(a.name);
  }
}
```

You can access the following information about the app:

1. Icon (will have to mention it in the `getInstalledApps` function call)
2. Name
3. Package Name
4. Version

You can also choose to exclude the system apps in the list as such:

```
List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true);
```

To get the icons in the list as well:

```
List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(false, true);
```

Comment: It works, but installed_apps uses "Query all packages" permission that creates problem while publishing app on play console

Comment: @codingPhobia so what did you use to get the app list or did you manage a solution when publishing the app in the play store using the installed_apps package

Comment: this is not use full on ```ios```

Answer (score 0):

recently I encountered this issue too, after a while I found social_share package on pub.dev.
but this package gradle version and structure was deprecated So I decided to Contribute it and fix this issue.
You can use my version through [social_share](https://github.com/hasanm08/social_share/tree/master) witch may be added to pub version with the help of authors and [my pull request](https://github.com/ShekarMudaliyar/social_share/pull/153).
But if it doesn't merged on pub version you can also access it with this lines on your `pubspec.yaml` file

```xml
  social_share:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/hasanm08/social_share.git
      ref: master
```